# Analog of harmonic oscillation to electrical circuit

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, harmonic-oscillator, capacitance, inductance

Equation of a damped harmonic oscillator under varying force $F$ is:

$$
m\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+\gamma m\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+Kx=F
$$

And the electric analog to this is:

$$
L\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 q}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+R\dfrac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{q}{C}=F
$$

In Feynman's first volume an example of this is taken as follows:

> Suppose we have designed an automobile, and want to know how much it is going to shake when it goes over a certain kind of bumpy road. We build an electric circuit with inductances to represent the inertia of the wheels, spring constants as capacitances to represent the spring of the wheels, and resistors to represent the shock absorbers and so on for the other parts of the automobile. For the bumpy road, we apply a voltage from a generator which represents such and such kind of a bump and then we look at how the left wheel jiggles by measuring the charge on some capacitor.

My doubt is that, how does the road bump represent the voltage? Isn't voltage here an analogue of an alternating force? And why is the resistance the shock absorbers? Do they resist the motion somehow?

Comment: The bump will be represented by a suitable changing voltage. A smooth road would be a constant voltage. The shock absorbers have to correspond to the resistances because they are the main energy absorbers in the systems.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage is across the capacitor, so you are really measure $q$ via:

$$ q = CV $$

and charge is direct analog of displacement.